# Using nth child to select one particular sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, overlay

I am hosting three images from Google on my codepen demo.

I have built image overlays which add a semi-transparent overlay when a user hovers over them.

They're working fine, but due to the colour of the last one, it looks much darker when hovered over than the other two.

I wondered whether there was a way to select the last image using the nth child (or similar) selector so that I could style that with a lower opacity irrespective of the other two, which I want to keep the same.

Here's the codepen link - http://codepen.io/skoster7/pen/ozgjmP?editors=1100

Like I said, I would like the last image to have a lower opacity then the other two, ideally using the nth-child selector or something similar.

I know I could just use a separate overlay with a different class name, but wanted to know if this was possible before doing that.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
}
.spr,
.wint,
.aut {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.overlay {
  transition: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 12.5px 0 0 5px;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:hover {
  transition-delay: .2s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  opacity: .6;
}
.overlay p {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
}
.photocontainer:last-child .overlay:hover {
  rgba(20, 5, 5, 0.35);
  text-
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">


  <div class="photocontainer">
    <img class="spr" src="http://www.thehealthyveggie.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/spring-daffodils_2845661b.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
      <p>Spring is here</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="photocontainer">
    <img class="wint" src="http://www.outsideonline.com/sites/default/files/styles/full-page/public/winter-bucket-list-2015-igloos_h.jpg?itok=RbGFkDiq">
    <div class="overlay">
      <p>Winter is here</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="photocontainer">
    <img class="aut" src="http://www.idealmagazine.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Autumn-10.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
      <p>Autumn is here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you could target each one of them using `nth-child`, we are targeting parent element i.e. `.photocontainer` as they are of same `class name` in all three images.

```
.photocontainer:nth-child(1) > .overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.photocontainer:nth-child(2) > .overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.photocontainer:nth-child(3) >  .overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex; 
}

.spr,
.wint,
.aut {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px; 
}

.overlay {
  transition: .5s; 
  position: absolute;
  margin: 12.5px 0 0 5px;
  top: 0;  
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black; 
  opacity: 0;   
  
}

.overlay:hover {
  transition-delay: .2s;
  transition-duration: 1s; 
}

.overlay p {
  font-size: 2em; 
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana; 
  text-align: center;  
}

.photocontainer:nth-child(1) > .overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.photocontainer:nth-child(2) > .overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.photocontainer:nth-child(3) >  .overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="flexcontainer">


    <div class="photocontainer"> <img class="spr" src="http://www.thehealthyveggie.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/spring-daffodils_2845661b.jpg">
      <div class="overlay"><p>Spring is here</p>
      </div>
      </div>


    <div class="photocontainer">  <img class="wint" src="http://www.outsideonline.com/sites/default/files/styles/full-page/public/winter-bucket-list-2015-igloos_h.jpg?itok=RbGFkDiq">
      <div class="overlay"> <p>Winter is here</p>
      </div>
      </div>


      <div class="photocontainer"><img class="aut" src="http://www.idealmagazine.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Autumn-10.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"><p>Autumn is here</p>
     </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. You don't have any idea how I could exempt the texts opacity from lowering irrespective of the overlays opacity do you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you target it. The `opacity` value is just for example.

```
.photocontainer:last-child .overlay:hover {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

[revised codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwbPZA?editors=1100)

The [`:last-child` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos) targets the last sibling of the same parent.

In your HTML, the third image is contained in the last `.photocontainer` div.

Once the focus is on the third container, you can use a [descendant selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) to target the image.

Also, keep in mind that the `opacity` property applies not only to the targeted element, but to all of the element's descendants, as well.

So when you reduce the opacity of `.overlay`, the text inside will also fade away.

The solution is to use the `rgba()` color method. The `a` stands for alpha channel, and allows you to apply transparency only to the color.

Add this to your code:

```
.photocontainer:last-child .overlay:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
```

[revised codepen illustrating both methods](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yayZWE?editors=1100)

(If you're applying `opacity` to an image, that's another ball game. You can find lots of posts on this site on that topic.)

References:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

**The issue of text opacity lowering  and last child opacity control both has been fixed**

Working example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/dpPrqv?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<div class="flexcontainer">


  <div class="photocontainer"> <img class="spr" src="http://www.thehealthyveggie.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/spring-daffodils_2845661b.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <p>Spring is here</p>
  </div>


  <div class="photocontainer"> <img class="wint" src="http://www.outsideonline.com/sites/default/files/styles/full-page/public/winter-bucket-list-2015-igloos_h.jpg?itok=RbGFkDiq">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <p>Winter is here</p>

  </div>


  <div class="photocontainer"><img class="aut" src="http://www.idealmagazine.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Autumn-10.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <p>Autumn is here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
}

.photocontainer,
.spr,
.wint,
.aut {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  transition: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 5px;
}

.photocontainer p {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.photocontainer:hover .overlay {
  transition-delay: .2s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.photocontainer:hover p {
  transition-delay: .2s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.photocontainer:hover:last-child .overlay {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Old:

```
.photocontainer:last-child .overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

I hope now your both issue has been resolved.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thats it, thanks a lot! Would you mind quickly explaining how/why that works if it doesn't take too long?

Comment: You can read more about [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild). I hope it helps :)

Comment: @skoster7 I have updated my code. I believe that your both issue has been fixed now. Please check the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/dpPrqv?editors=1100) link